# Codeigniter Multi Select insert values into database

Tags: php, codeigniter, multi-select

I have a form that uses a multi select so you can select multiple options, how would I make it so that if you pick 2 options, it adds them both into the database as

```
option1,option2,option3
```

I'm kind of still new to PHP, I know I will have to put it as an array, I'm just not sure exactly how to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use varchar field in data base table and then insert it. First take a php variable and assign all values to it should be comma seperated. then use this variable in your query to insert.
When you get values by select use explode function there.

Comment: Thanks, I got the rest from there :)

Comment: While being on the stack overflow you should accept answers vote up etc this will increase your and others reputation

Answer (score 1):

If you whant to have an array you can use the php `explode` function:

```
$your_options = "option1,option2,option3";
$array = explode(",", $your_option);
```

now you can access with `$array[0], $array[1]` and so on...